# Magento 1.7 product image import not assigning image to product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have done a CSV import of my products, and using [this walk-through](https://web.archive.org/web/20171112042856/http://www.meteorify.com:80/2012/05/importing-product-images-csv-magento-1-7-0-0) I have uploaded my images for each product. My problem is that although the image is being recognised as the image for the right product, the product is not saving the image as the one to be displayed (see screenshot below). How do I use the CSV upload (I am using a dataflow profile) to import and set the product images?

[image]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/y9GJ.png))</sub>

My CSV (for a single product) looks like:

```
sku,image,small_image,thumbnail
TT010,/TT010-350x200.jpg,/TT010-350x200.jpg,/TT010-350x200.jpg
```

Comment: Apologies for the tangential answer, but if you've never looked at MAGMI you may find it useful for future imports.

Comment: Every time I see someone struggling with magento imports I recommend MAGMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When viewing the products there is an option at the top left to view either default values or to view the values for the store. What I was viewing was the default values. When I changed this drop-down to the store values, then I saw that the images were being assigned.

[image]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/ya8U.jpeg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem occurring because of image positioning.

So Please Try this -

**sku, image, small_image, thumbnail, _media_image, _media_attribute_id, _media_position, _media_is_disabled

123, /Agent700.jpg, /Agent700.jpg, /Agent700.jpg, /Agent700.jpg, 88, 1, 0**

Make your CSV as per the above norms and change the column as per your requirement but do not change 88 which is _media_attribute_id. and keep 1,0 for _media_position & _media_is_disabled.

I have tried this and works perfectly.

Hope It'll helpful for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used this step and it works.

1. see the Id of 'media_gallery' in database->eav_attribute (in my version it is 703)
2. in the csv file, add this column: _media_image, _media_attribute_id, _media_position, _media_is_disabled
   _media_image : same value as image or small_image
   _media_attribute_id : is the Id that you've seen in step 1.
   _media_position for first image is : 1
   and set _media_is_disabled to 0
3. Use Import tool in admin!

Answer (score 0):

MAGMI is the best way to do this. Otherwise the importing of the products is always a head pain from my experience.

In MAGMI, in order to get multiple images imported as a media gallery, all you need is:

1) define field **media_gallery** in you CSV and populate it like this:

*/image1.jpg;/image2.png/image3.jpeg*

2) Install MAGMI plugin images attribute processor

3) Store your images in the folder that you defined as "media import" folder in MAGMI settings before importing

More details here:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Those who consider paid extensions for easy resolving this task, take a look at [this one](http://productuploader.magelynx.com) which fully integrates MAGMI into Magento and allows more handy features.

Comment: Hi @Rob, thanks for the suggestion of Magmi. I have used it since this issue so going forward this will not be an issue; however I shall leave my answer as is for anyone else who has had the same issue...